# "not so useful as" vs "not as useful as"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, negation, nuance, so-vs-as

I do not understand whether the first or the second sentence is correct, or perhaps both?

1. No other metal is **so useful as** iron.
2. No other metal is **as useful as** iron.

Although the latter feels correct to me. Any light shed on the above would be much appreciated!

Comment: They mean the same thing, but the first form is more archaic.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco That's wrong.